# Сортировка по зависимостям

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, сортировка

Есть список объектов, у них есть поле, в котором указаны зависимости

```
class A:
    dependencies = []

class B:
    dependencies = []

class C:
    dependencies = [A]

class D:
    dependencies = [B]

class E:
    dependencies = [A, B, C]

class F:
    dependencies = [E]

class G:
    dependencies = [F]
```

Изначально весь набор объектов валиден, все объекты в зависимостях имеются, нет цикличности.

Как отсортировать произвольный набор объектов по зависимостям?

Порядок должен быть такой:

1. Объект встает в список если все зависимости уже добавлены
2. Если нет какой либо зависимости, ждем пока она появится
3. Если не осталось объектов с полными зависимостями, то добавляем объекты независимые от уже добавленных
4. см п 1 (по кругу) пока изначальный список не будет полностью в новом

Подскажите алгоритм?

Примеры входных/выходных данных

```
> [A, C, E, B, D]
< [A, B, C, D, E] или [A, B, D, C, E]
```

```
> [B, E, A, D, G, F]
< [B, A, D, E, F, G]
```

---

Предполагаю, сначала надо пройтись по объектам и записать, какие объекты зависят от них, и смотреть исходя из этих данных

Comment: См. **топологическая сортировка**.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Топологическая_сортировка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На основе полученных комментарием, нашел [библиотеку для топологической сортировки](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/klass-topologicalsorter-modulja-graphlib-python/).

```
>>> import graphlib
>>> graph = {"D": {"B", "C"}, "C": {"A"}, "B": {"A"}}
>>> ts = graphlib.TopologicalSorter(graph)
>>> tuple(ts.static_order())
('A', 'C', 'B', 'D')
```

Это решило проблему без костылизации и велосепедолизации

Спасибо